# Sending & Receiving SMS in Netbeans SMSLIB

Tags: netbeans, smslib

I am working on a project in which im sending sms and receiving them in computer through SMSLIB where a mobile is connected to my computer via Bluetooth. I have to get the mobile number of that mobile which is connected to my computer but i am unable to find a function for it. Kindly help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is a late response, and you might already have the answer, but the fact is that you can't. you have to know the number of the SIM card that your modem (or phone) is using.

I usually set the gateway ID to be the phone number. that helps with debugging and whatnot, especially if you have multiple modems.